# Text downward shift when viewing webpage in Windows

Tags: html, css, font-family

After developing a page in Ubuntu, I viewed it in Windows 7.
I found a slight downward shift in the text when viewed in Windows.

The left image below is a screenshot from **Google Chrome on Ubuntu 11.04**
The right image is a screenshot from **Google Chrome on Windows 7**

[image: Ubuntu 11.04: Google Chrome] [image: Windows 7: Google Chrome]

Notice the **downward text shift** in the right image. The same effect is visible in both Chrome and Firefox on both the platforms. (IE also, if anyone is interested)

Is this due to different fonts being used in Windows?
The font stack I'm using here is -

```
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
```

Although I've also tried using a simple stack like -

```
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

but the problem still exists. If this is due to change of fonts, can I use a CSS hack to raise the font by a small margin in Windows?

**NOTE** that I'm using Paul Irish's HTML5 boilerplate - which includes a CSS-reset.

Comment: The text is perfectly aligned between the two images. However, the second image seems to be entirely shifted down by a few pixels. Doesn't seem to be a text issue at all.

Comment: @Polynomial look at the white buttons.

Comment: Ah yes. It's not even a pixel different, though!

Comment: @Polynomial silly question but are both the fonts aligned at the bottom? Windows font smaller height? I'm definitely seeing a shift..

Comment: Perhaps. You could try `vertical-align: middle`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a vertical-align issue. Make sure that your `margin`, `padding` and ESPECIALLY `line-height` values are set for that text. I recommend using percentages for `line-height` (e.g. 120%)